# Prevent mouse cursor freeze under load

Tags: cursor

In Windows 10 I seem to always be able to move the mouse cursor — no matter how much CPU the current app is using I always seem to be able to move the mouse (and use the task bar). I value this a lot. In fact I find it essential to avoid the feeling of "the system might possibly be frozen indefinitely now" every few seconds.

On Ubuntu (17.10) the cursor will just grind to a halt as soon as there is significant load on the CPU. In those moments it feels like the whole system is a single-threaded JavaScript web app. Every few seconds during high CPU/disk load it freezes for a few seconds as if the cursor is hitting the disk or something. I can't imagine what it could possibly be waiting for, except execution time.

Is there a way to change this, by e.g. editing priorities of certain processes?